# setting background color using javascript works in every browser but Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I use the following function to allow a website user to click on a gray oval and see an indigo oval with a white check mark when they 'select' it, and back to a gray oval when they 'deselect' it.
It works exactly the way I want it to on every browser except Chrome 42.0.2311.90. On Chrome it works fine when 'selecting' it, but the background color doesn't change from indigo to dark gray when clicking it a second time to 'deselect' it.

```php
<script type=\"text/javascript\">

function clickeditem(checkaccount) {
    if (document.getElementById(checkaccount).style.backgroundColor==\"indigo\"){
        document.getElementById(checkaccount).style.backgroundColor=\"darkgray\";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(checkaccount).style.backgroundColor=\"indigo\";
    }
    if (document.getElementById(checkaccount).style.color==\"white\"){
        document.getElementById(checkaccount).style.color=\"darkgray\";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(checkaccount).style.color=\"white\";
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Why are all those quotes escaped? That's going to cause a few problems.

Comment: it's in a php file using echo

Comment: Further, please take the time to post code that can be read and understood; next time *look* at the preview to see how it'll look to everyone else. If it looks wrong, look at the formatting help to the side of the editing/preview box.

Comment: @DavidThomas I did edit for correct formatting but looks like you and Thomas have gone over that edit. Good job too because i didn't see the escaped quotes in the script tags. I did see it in the javascript but not in the tags.

Comment: Use [`heredoc`](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax and things will be more readable and maintainable.

Comment: this code works fine assuming you're doing something like this http://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/14085/

Comment: It works in every browser I can get my hands on, except Chrome.

Comment: Can you confirm that this fiddle does not work for you: http://fiddle.jshell.net/99550tLc/show/ ?? For what specific version of chrome on what platform?

Comment: That doesn't work on my browser.  When I click on it, nothing happens.  I looked at the Chrome version and it updated, but still doesn't work.  It now says Version 42.0.2311.90 m.  I am on Windows 7.

Comment: Try this one, look at the console log: http://jsfiddle.net/qr3Ln5v5/

Comment: So much repetitive code...

Answer (score 1):

Chrome 42.0.2311.90 seems to mess with the casing of named colors since adding a `.toLowerCase()` solves the problem for the asker.
The asker [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661904/setting-background-color-using-javascript-works-in-every-browser-but-chrome#comment47465769_29661904) that my fiddle works for him: http://jsfiddle.net/99550tLc/

Here is a stack-snippet of that (which also simplifies the code and makes it a lot easier on the DOM):

```js
function clickeditem(checkaccount){
    checkaccount=document.getElementById(checkaccount);
    if(checkaccount.style.color.toLowerCase() === 'white'){
       checkaccount.style.color = checkaccount.style.backgroundColor = 'darkgray';
    } else {
       checkaccount.style.backgroundColor = 'indigo';
       checkaccount.style.color = 'white';
    }
}
```

```css
#tst{
    display: inline;
    width: 1em;
    border-radius:0.4em;
    background-color: darkgray;
    color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
Select click to select option: 
<div id="tst" onclick="clickeditem('tst');">&#x2714;</div>
```

Comment: How did you find this? Does chrome offer HTML guidelines?
Your solution didn't work for me (possibly different chrome version), but now I know it's chrome's problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following works, thanks to GitaarLAB!

```
function clickeditem(checkaccount) {
    checkaccount=document.getElementById(checkaccount);
    //change color
        if(checkaccount.style.color.toLowerCase() === 'white'){
           checkaccount.style.color = checkaccount.style.backgroundColor = 'darkgray';
        } else {
           checkaccount.style.backgroundColor = 'indigo';
           checkaccount.style.color = 'white';
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are welcome. However, please note that it is not usual to repeat an answer that worked for you, instead, accept the answer (and upvote it if you like it) that helped you the most. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399 for a good explanation. Might I also suggest to delete this duplicate answer you have posted (see this image for help: http://i57.tinypic.com/2utq8vr.jpg)? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, but there was no answer only comments.  There is no way to upvote or interact with a comment.  On another thread I saw they said to answer your own question to close it.  With a solution in the comments and no answers present, that's what I did.  Thank you all for the help.

Comment: What you read is correct regarding reposting a solution given in a comment (good on you for reading the SO-Policy !!) *However*.. I posted my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29663288/588079) 34 minutes *before* you reposted it (as thanks and confirmation that it worked).. So I'd still politely suggest you close your question by accepting my answer (the solution you are using) and removing your identical copy.. Thanks!